# Selenium with Python 3 - How to click on element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am new to Selenium I have been following the documentations but they seem outdated.

(for curious people, that is the admin section of Atlassian's Cloud https://admin.atlassian.com/s/orgID/users/userID, I wish to remove site access for multiple users)

Here is a subset of the HTML page:

```html
<label data-size="regular" class="css-ji2l50" data-checked="true">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="123456789abcde">
        <span role="img" aria-label="check" class="css-zg81aj">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation">
                <path d="M7.356 10.942a.497.497 0 00-.713 0l-.7.701a.501.501 0 00-.003.71l3.706 3.707a.501.501 0 00.705.003l7.712-7.712a.493.493 0 00-.006-.708l-.7-.7a.504.504 0 00-.714 0l-6.286 6.286a.506.506 0 01-.713 0l-2.288-2.287z" fill="currentColor"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <span role="img" aria-label="cross" class="css-zg81aj">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation">
                <path d="M15.185 7.4l-3.184 3.185-3.186-3.186a.507.507 0 00-.712.003l-.7.701a.496.496 0 00-.004.712l3.185 3.184L7.4 15.185a.507.507 0 00.004.712l.7.7c.206.207.516.2.712.004l3.186-3.185 3.184 3.185a.507.507 0 00.712-.004l.701-.7a.496.496 0 00.003-.712l-3.186-3.186 3.186-3.184a.507.507 0 00-.003-.712l-.7-.7a.508.508 0 00-.36-.153.5.5 0 00-.353.15z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
</label>
```

I want to capture and click on `<input name="" type="checkbox" value="123456789abcde">`

Since there is no `element = driver.find_element(By.VALUE,"123456789abcde")` ([link to the documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interacting-with-webpage-selenium-python/))
I am using `element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='123456789abcde']")`

This seems to work fine, `print(element)` gives `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b2d92d7e20334085b7989c009fa77785", element="c23fdd99-9052-4028-9a72-e8f39873c720")>`

But `element.click()` results in a ElementClickInterceptedException exception.
`element.click` does return `<bound method WebElement.click of <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b2d92d7e20334085b7989c009fa77785", element="c23fdd99-9052-4028-9a72-e8f39873c720")>>` but the button is not toggled.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Note that I am using Edge webdriver if that matters.

Thanks.

EDIT: From first investigations, it seems that the the `<label>` is overlapping the input.
If I indeed click on the label itself it does toggle the button.
In the page code above, I tested my code on the xpath `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@data-checked='true']").click()` but the thing is that there are several labels on the page that show a data-checked='true' property.
How to craft the xpath so that I select the label associated with that specific input. Basically mixing the "//label[@data-checked='true']" and //input[@value='123456789abcde'] xpaths.

Comment: We need an access to that page in order to debug and see what exactly appears there. Generally `ElementClickInterceptedException exception` means that when you tried to click some element another element received the click. To make a simple check try adding a sleep before clicking that element. In case it worked we will improve that

Comment: Hi, I am actually executing the commands one by one so I do not think a sleep will solve the issue.
Unfortunately the source page is not accessible. It is always possible for you to open a Jira cloud site then go to the "user management" section.

Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: If so there should be some element hovering that element.

Comment: Also, performing the commands one by one is done during debugging only. In the real code run it will work differently ...

Comment: Though, printing `print(element.tag_name)` returns "input" so I believe that this is the proper input which is selected.

Note that I am able to click on the element in Edge javascript console `document.querySelectorAll('input[value="123456789abcde"]')[0].click()`

Comment: That says your locator is correct. Also JavaScript can click any element: out of the view, below other elements etc. While Selenium behaves as a human user. As a user you can't click element inside drop list before you open it etc.

Comment: Thanks for your precision. Infact I tried clicking on the `<label>` that is infact overlaping the `<input>` (I saw that after this message) and it did toggle the button. The issue now is that I do not know how to properly select the appropriate "label" since only the "input" has a clear value that I can target. The 'label' does not feature any ID/name/value whatsoever
I will edit the original post since

Comment: In case `label` is a direct parent of the `input` the XPath can be changed simply. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have no access to that page we can only guess.
So, instead of `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='123456789abcde']").click()`  Try adding a wait. The WebdriverWait is the preferred way to do that, as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='123456789abcde']"))).click()
```

**UPD**
In case you need to click the `label` element which is a direct parent of this `input` the locator can be updated as following:

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='123456789abcde']/.."))).click()
```

Another way to precisely locate that `label` is to find the parent `div` based on the child `input` and from it to get the child `label` as following:

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[.//input[@value='123456789abcde']]//label"))).click()
```

Comment: I receive a TimeoutException. Seems like the element is never clickable.
Though in the developer console it is.
`document.evaluate("//input[@value='123456789abcde']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()`

Comment: Sure, as I said before, seems that there is some other element overlaps it. To resolve this I need an access to that page....